# Is there an analog of the Kirchhoff integral theorem applied to the Schrodinger equation?

Tags: schroedinger-equation

The Kirchhoff integral formula is a powerful tool that allows us to compute solutions to the standard wave equation given certain 2D boundary conditions.

Is there anything similar that holds for the Schrodinger equation?

I suspect the answer is no, because one of the key properties of the wave equation is that its solutions have "finite speed propagation" whereas solutions to the Schrodinger equation don't take into account the finite speed of causality and a "dirac delta solution" may have instantaneous effects arbitrarily far away.

If not, are there references that discuss anything related to this?

Comment: What refs are you using for the Kirchhoff integral formula?

Comment: @user45664 I have [the equations on this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff_integral_theorem#Monochromatic_waves) in mind, but if we need a more formal reference, I'm thinking about _Hecht_ Appendix 2.